# What is the type of Java 8 constructor reference?

Tags: lambda, types, java-8

With the following model:

```
package supplier;

public interface Shape {
    void draw();

    public static class Rectangle implements Shape {
        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("Inside Rectangle::draw() method.");
        }
    }

    public static class Circle implements Shape {
        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("Inside Circle::draw() method.");
        }
    }

    public static class Square implements Shape {
        @Override
        public void draw() {
            System.out.println("Inside Square::draw() method.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how Java determines the type of a lambda expression returned by a constructor reference:

```
    Shape square = Square::new;
    System.out.println("square: "+square);

    Supplier<Shape> suppSquare = Square::new;
    System.out.println("suppSquare: "+suppSquare);
```

---

```
square: supplier.ShapeFactoryTest$$Lambda$11/183264084@1c655221
suppSquare: supplier.ShapeFactoryTest$$Lambda$12/1490180672@1b701da1
```

Both cases seem to be returning lambdas however the following doesn't compile:

```
square = suppSquare;
```

How then does it resolve lambda to the underlying type in the first case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Shape interface is a functional interface, since it has a single abstract method `draw()`. This method doesn't take any argument, and returns nothing. It's thus similar to a Runnable.

The constructor of Square doesn't take any argument, and what it "returns" (or rather, creates) can be ignored. So it's usable as an implementation of the `Shape` functional interface: its signature is compatible. That's why you are allowed to use

```
Shape square = Square::new;
```

which defines a variable `square` of type `Shape`.

This doesn't make a lot of sense though, since when calling draw() on the variable `square`, you probably expect some drawing to happen. But that won't happen. The constructor of `Square` will just be invoked, that's all.

And doing

```
square = suppSquare;
```

can't possibly work, since square is a variable of type Shape, and Shape isn't a supertype of `Supplier<Shape>`.

Comment: Based on your reasoning above, would it then imply that in the second case of constructor reference it accepts the assignment of the lambda to `Supplier<Shape>` just because Shape's constructor matches `Supplier#get` signature.  Does it then mean that lambda could be assigned to different types which are in no way related?  Does constructor reference have a specific type that Java gives it during obj. creation?  What's confusing is that while the RHS is of the same type, why can't the LHS's be assined, i.e. ```Number pi = new Double(3.14);
  Double dPi = new Double(3.14);
  
  pi = dPi;```

Comment: First part: yes. A Supplier<Shape> is a function that doesn't take any input and produces a Shape. The Square constructor matches: it doesn't take any argument, and produces a Square, which is a Shape. *Does it then mean that lambda could be assigned to different types which are in no way related?* yes. What matters is that the signature and return type are compatible. For example, a method `int foo(A a1, A a2)` can be used as a Comparator<A>, or as a ToIntBiFunction<A, A>.